# Parsing Json From PHP to Xcode(Swift) with Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, json, xcode

Morning All, 
Im after a bit of advice/help with the below issue. 
i have tried looking around and google'ing but I still don't understand where I'm going wrong. Please forgive me as I'm a complete noob at this.

some of you may have seem this code before but I'm want to adapt it. Once the user logs in i want to get the user ID from the MySQL Database and send that to swift in the JSON but i can't get it to work, i have tried putting the query in different places with no luck, JSON is completely new to me :(

Ideally > user logs in> swift sends JSON to verify>JSON-PHP verified by MySQL > PHP - JSON reply with success AND user id from the db.

Any Help would be amazing !!

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
require("conn.php");
if($_POST) {
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];

if($username && $password) {

        $db_name     = '***';
        $db_user     = '***';
        $db_password = '***';
        $server_url  = 'localhost';

        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            error_log("Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"' . mysqli_connect_error() . '"}';
        } else {
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?")) {

                $password = md5($password);

                /* bind parameters for markers */
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

                /* execute query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* bind result variables */
                $stmt->bind_result($id);

                /* fetch value */
                $stmt->fetch();

                /* close statement */
                $stmt->close();
            }

            /* close connection */
            $mysqli->close();

            if ($id) {


                error_log("User $username: password match.");
                echo '{"success":1, "ID":0}';
            } else {
                error_log("User $username: password doesn\'t match.");
                echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username/Password"}';
            }
        }
} else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username/Password."}';
}
}else {echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Data."}';
}

?>
```